# Applying a CSS3 transform to an SVG element in Safari

Tags: animation, css, safari, svg

I am using SVGs to build up a cartoon style street scene, and I wanted to have clouds scrolling across the scene. To do this, I was using a setTimeout or requestAnimationFrame (dependant on browser) to update the SVGs (x) position, but the FPS counter dropped from 30fps to 7fps on the **iPad** because of it. I tried again using SVG transform="translate(x, y)" to see if performance increased. It did not.

Finally, I thought I would try with CSS3 transforms, and applied it directly to the SVG element:

This worked fine in chrome, and firefox. But Safari (including iPad) doesn't seem to accept having css transforms on an SVG.

Is this a known bug? Or is there a way around this? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Okay, I'm not sure if I'm 100% right about this, but it seems that setting the "x" value of a transform every frame for any kind of movement (especially in a complex parallax situation where at least 5 layers are moving at the same time) is a very bad idea.

Also after much research it appears SVG1.1 does not support CSS3 transforms across all browsers for certain. SVG transforms are okay but CSS3 is not.

**Finally to fix this solution:** I simply reset all x, y positions to (0, 0), and positioned everything with *-webkit-transform: translate3d(x, y, z)*. (and variations of for other browsers).

Note: I use translate3d even for a 2d parallax effect and leave z at 0. translate3d is hardware accelerated and has a visible performance increase on the iPad.

Comment: And yes, I did just answer my own question :)

Comment: Why not use _.debounce or throttle so it doesn't change it for *every* movement?

Answer (score -1):

I have no problem with this, you must be doing something wrong.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/pqyBJ/

Comment: I assume Simon wants to apply CSS3 transform on an inner SVGElement and not the root.

Comment: But it doesn't work on IE11, is there anyway to handle in IE ?